# Oracle SQL select query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table:

```
select * from scott.test;

a   b   c
---------
26  R   4
26  T   5
26  S   2
25  Y   2
25  U   3
24  X   3
22  Z   3
21  P   3
```

What i need is this: 
For a given "a" i have to extract all the details (a,b,c) and if there are more then one "a", i want to extract only the one with the highest "c".
Example, for 26, i want to extract only:

```
a  b  c
26 T  5
```

I have done this in this way:

```
select * from scott.test where a = 26 and c = (select max(c) from scott.test where a = 26);
```

but I need it with only one select (not select within select). Could it be done? Thank you!

Comment: You need to use **CASE** and **ROW_NUMBER** analytic function. And what do you mean by **asap** in your question? To get an answer ASAP, you should provide a working test case. Create and insert statements. At least SQL Fiddle. Showing the data is no help to who wants to help you. You execute a SQL on a table, so just looking at the data people could only *GUESS* and not give you perfectly correct answer.

Comment: @LalitKumarB I think he wants the answer asap (as soon as possible) - *which I think is quite rude*

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu I know. I am explaining that to OP.

Answer (score 1):

Using **ROW_NUMBER()** analytic function you could achieve it. However, you will need to do it using a sub-query. But you could always look it different using **WITH** clause.

The below query would prompt you to enter the value for column `a`, and return you the row with maximum value of column `c`. The first part of the WITH clause is only to build sample data for demonstration, you only need the second part, i.e. `t`.

For example,

Enter value for `a` as `26`:

```
SQL> WITH data AS
  2    (SELECT 26 AS a, 'R' AS b, 4 AS c FROM dual
  3    UNION ALL
  4    SELECT 26 AS a, 'T' AS b, 5 AS c FROM dual
  5    UNION ALL
  6    SELECT 26 AS a, 'S' AS b, 2 AS c FROM dual
  7    UNION ALL
  8    SELECT 25 AS a, 'Y' AS b, 2 AS c FROM dual
  9    UNION ALL
 10    SELECT 25 AS a, 'U' AS b, 3 AS c FROM dual
 11    UNION ALL
 12    SELECT 24 AS a, 'X' AS b, 3 AS c FROM dual
 13    UNION ALL
 14    SELECT 22 AS a, 'Z' AS b, 3 AS c FROM dual
 15    UNION ALL
 16    SELECT 21 AS a, 'P' AS b, 3 AS c FROM dual
 17    ),
 18    t AS
 19    ( SELECT a,b,c,row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY a ORDER BY c DESC) rn FROM DATA
 20    )
 21  SELECT a,b,c FROM t WHERE a = &1 AND rn = 1;
Enter value for 1: 26
old  21: SELECT a,b,c FROM t WHERE a = &1 AND rn = 1
new  21: SELECT a,b,c FROM t WHERE a = 26 AND rn = 1

         A B          C
---------- - ----------
        26 T          5
```

Enter value for `a` as `25`:

```
SQL> WITH data AS
  2    (SELECT 26 AS a, 'R' AS b, 4 AS c FROM dual
  3    UNION ALL
  4    SELECT 26 AS a, 'T' AS b, 5 AS c FROM dual
  5    UNION ALL
  6    SELECT 26 AS a, 'S' AS b, 2 AS c FROM dual
  7    UNION ALL
  8    SELECT 25 AS a, 'Y' AS b, 2 AS c FROM dual
  9    UNION ALL
 10    SELECT 25 AS a, 'U' AS b, 3 AS c FROM dual
 11    UNION ALL
 12    SELECT 24 AS a, 'X' AS b, 3 AS c FROM dual
 13    UNION ALL
 14    SELECT 22 AS a, 'Z' AS b, 3 AS c FROM dual
 15    UNION ALL
 16    SELECT 21 AS a, 'P' AS b, 3 AS c FROM dual
 17    ),
 18    t AS
 19    ( SELECT a,b,c,row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY a ORDER BY c DESC) rn FROM DATA
 20    )
 21  SELECT a,b,c FROM t WHERE a = &1 AND rn = 1;
Enter value for 1: 25
old  21: SELECT a,b,c FROM t WHERE a = &1 AND rn = 1
new  21: SELECT a,b,c FROM t WHERE a = 25 AND rn = 1

         A B          C
---------- - ----------
        25 U          3
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this? -

```
WITH test
     AS (SELECT 26 AS a, 'R' AS b, 4 AS c FROM dual
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 26 AS a, 'T' AS b, 5 AS c FROM dual
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 26 AS a, 'S' AS b, 2 AS c FROM dual
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 25 AS a, 'Y' AS b, 2 AS c FROM dual
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 25 AS a, 'U' AS b, 3 AS c FROM dual
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 24 AS a, 'X' AS b, 3 AS c FROM dual
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 22 AS a, 'Z' AS b, 3 AS c FROM dual
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 21 AS a, 'P' AS b, 3 AS c FROM dual)
SELECT a, b, c
  FROM (SELECT a, b, c, max(c) OVER (PARTITION BY a) AS max_c
          FROM test
        WHERE A = 26)
 WHERE c = max_c
```

Comment: It doesn't really look like .. one select, but two, even if they're nested.

Comment: If @user3913719 told about single table scan, then doesn't matter how many subqueries is. Dunno what "not select within select" is mean :)

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, but did OP mention anything about table scans?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It probably should work :).

```
  select a,max(b) keep (dense_rank first order by c desc) b , max(c) keep (dense_rank first order by c desc) c from test
    where a = 26
    group by a
```